# How to retrieve the post's likes on facebook api?

Tags: api, rest, facebook, facebook-graph-api

my request is: `https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/page-id_post-id?fields=likes.summary(true)`

my permissions are - read_insights, pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_read_user_content

but I'm getting empty data:

```
{
    "likes": {
        "data": [],
        "paging": {
            "cursors": {
                "before": $,
                "after": $
            },
            "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/page-id_post-id/likes?access_token=$&summary=true&limit=25&after=$"
        },
        "summary": {
            "total_count": 35,
            "can_like": true,
            "has_liked": false
        }
    },
    "id": "page-id_post-id"
}
```

Any idea?